# Добавление новой записи в файл

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Есть класс сериалайзера

```
public static void SaveObject(T data, string fileName)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    //var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Data.txt"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, data);
    }
}
```

а так же файл с переменными

```
public AuthData()
        : this(string.Empty, string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public AuthData(string login, string password)
    {
        Login = login;
        Password = password;
    }

    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Через два текстбокса я добавляю логин и пароль, при сохранении создается файл, в котором имеются записи  ..  Сам вопрос - как добавить запись с новыми параметрами логин и пароль - без перезаписи их?

добавление происходит таким методом

```
var authData = new AuthData(tb1.Text, tb2.Text);       
DataSerializer<AuthData>.SaveObject(authData, 
    LocalConfiguration.Instance.Files.AuthDataFile);
```

Comment: Дополню - добавление происходит таким методом  {var authData = new AuthData(tb1.Text, tb2.Text);
            DataSerializer<AuthData>.SaveObject(authData, LocalConfiguration.Instance.Files.AuthDataFile);}

Comment: Вопрос в том как дописывать в файл, вместо того, чтобы его постоянно перезаписывать, так?

Comment: А что вы хотите, чтобы было в файле? Только последний логин/пароль или все? И собираетесь ли вы потом эту информацию **де**сериализовывать?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, Вам не нравится, что файл постоянно перезаписывается, и Вы хотите каждый новый AuthData дописывать в конец файла, вместо его перезаписи. Если это так, то решение элементарно, нужно добавить `true` к конструированию `StreamWriter`:

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Data.txt", true))
```

Если Вы посмотрите на документацию [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx), то станет очевидно, почему нам нужно добавить `true`.

Comment: Но в файле же будет невалидный XML

Comment: @VladD, ну там будет несколько валидных :) Не очень понятно, что конкретно нужно автору

Comment: Угу, переспросил в комментах

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код является ответом, но не в моем случае, в виду структуры генерируемого документа(она повторяется снова).. Сделал так, теперь работает. Спасибо всем

```
var path = LocalConfiguration.Instance.Files.AuthDataFile;

List<AuthData> authData;
if (File.Exists(path))
    authData = DataSerializer<List<AuthData>>.LoadObject(path);
else
    authData = new List<AuthData>();

authData.Add(new AuthData(tb1.Text, tb2.Text));
DataSerializer<List<AuthData>>.SaveObject(authData, path);
```